# PHP - Multidimentional array filtering by given value

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( 
    [01755677011] => Array ( 

        [0] => Array ( 

            [0] => 1 
            [id] => 1 
            [1] => 01755677011 
            [phone_num] => 01755677011 
            [2] => NoAnswer 
            [status] => Answer 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 

            [0] => 2 
            [id] => 2 
            [1] => 01755677011 
            [phone_num] => 01755677011 
            [2] => NoAnswer 
            [status] => NoAnswer 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 

            [0] => 3 
            [id] => 3 
            [1] => 01755677011 
            [phone_num] => 01755677011 
            [2] => Answer 
            [status] => NoAnswer 
        ) 
        [3] => Array ( 

            [0] => 4 
            [id] => 4 
            [1] => 01755677011 
            [phone_num] => 01755677011 
            [2] => Answer 
            [status] => Answer 
        )
    )
    [01755677012] => Array (

        [0] => Array ( 

            [0] => 16 
            [id] => 16 
            [1] => 01755677012 
            [phone_num] => 01755677012 
            [2] =>No Answer 
            [status] => NoAnswer 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 

            [0] => 18 
            [id] => 18 
            [1] => 01755677012 
            [phone_num] => 01755677012 
            [2] => Answer 
            [status] => Answer
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

This is my current array. I want to filter only Answer status by phone_num.
Outpout Will Like this:

```
Phone Num   No of answer  
01755677011 0,23  
01755677012 1
```

Can anyone helo me please ??

Comment: how you get no of answer column values in your desired output? i din't see any type of those value in your input array

Comment: $qry_num_fetch="SELECT * FROM phnno_tbl";
  $exc_qry=mysqli_query($conn,$qry_num_fetch);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($exc_qry))
  {
   $num[]=$row;
  }  
  
  $result = array();
  foreach ($num as $element) {
    $result[$element['phone_num']][] = $element;
    $res[$element['phone_num']] = $element;
   }  
  foreach($res as $key=>$values)
  {
   $number[]= $key;   
   
  }  
  //print_r($result[$number][0]['status']);
  print_r($result);
Actually its my query result data. I want to filter this array by Answer and finally get output the key of Answer group by phone num.

Comment: I still dont understand how do you get the "No of Answer" values, is it a function of the "status"=Answer/NoAnswer?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how you get 0,23 for 01755677011. If you are displaying phone_num and the number of times it has "Answer" status, you can do it this way:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($num as $key => $row) {
    $result[$key] = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($row as $key_value => $row_value) {
        if ($row_value['status'] == 'Answer') {
            // $key is the key 01755677011 and 01755677012
            $result[$key]['id'][$count] = $row_value['id'];
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($result)) {
    echo "Phone Num | No of answer<br />";
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
        echo $key . " " . count($row['id']) . "<br />";        
    }
}
```

Second version:

1) Based on "Answer" in either [status] or [2].

2) Display array index of the corresponding phone_num.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($num as $key => $row) {
    $result[$key] = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($row as $key_value => $row_value) {
        if ($row_value['2'] == 'Answer' || $row_value['status'] == 'Answer') {
            // $key is the key 01755677011 and 01755677012
            $result[$key][$count]['index'] = $key_value;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);

if (!empty($result)) {
    echo "Phone Num | No of answer<br />";
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
        echo $key . " | ";
        if (!empty($row)) {
            foreach ($row as $data_key => $data) {
                echo $data['index'];
            }
        } else {
            echo "No record";
        }
        echo "<br />"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i want the no of answer time regarding phone number. If we see the array, we can see against the 01755677011- Total answer time is 3. First 0 no key then 2 no key and last 3 no key. That means This (01755677011 ) num has answered for first time then 3rd time then fourth time. So finally i want to get result, how many time it was Answered and and when it was Answered after Noanswer.
Simply i want just key no of Answer regarding phone number.

Comment: I still do not understand. There are 4 attempts for 01755677011. I do not see where the 3 is coming from. Unless you are looking at the array index like [01755677011][0], [01755677011][2], [01755677011][3]?

Comment: And also when you say "Answered", does it mean [status] or also "[2] => Answer"?

Comment: I've updated my suggested answer if I got your points correct - You are looking for "Answer" in both [status] and [2] and you want to display the array index.